# Python: How to get the statistics of the position of each item in multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I want to analyze the sequences items of the items and the positions in the sequence where the item appear.

For example:

```
dataframe['sequence_list'][0] = ['a','b', 'f', 'e']
dataframe['sequence_list'][1] = ['a','c', 'd', 'e']
dataframe['sequence_list'][2] = ['a','d']
...
dataframe['sequence_list'][i] = ['a','b', 'c']
```

What I want to get is:
How many times 'a' appear in position 0, 1, 2, 3 of the list ?
How many times 'b' appear in position 0, 1, 2, 3 of the list ?
...

Output would be like:

```
output[1,'a'] = 4
output[2,'a'] = 0
output[3,'a'] = 0
output[4,'a'] = 0
output[1,'b'] = 2
...
```

The output format could be different. I just want to tell if there are any quick matrix computing methodology help me get the stats quickly?

Comment: What data type is `dataframe`?  Since you didn't tag this with `Pandas`; I'm wondering whether it might be a dictionary.  Either way, counting frequencies is documented well in other questions.

Comment: it's Pandas.dataframe

Comment: I want to get the index counting instead of the item counting, are there any solutions have been posted? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by converting the lists into Series using one of the two statements:

```
df_ser = dataframe.sequence_list.apply(pd.Series)
df_ser = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.sequence_list.tolist()) # ~30% faster?
```

The columns of the new dataframe are item positions for each row:

```
#   0  1    2    3
#0  a  b    f    e
#1  a  c    d    e
#2  a  d  NaN  NaN
#3  a  b    c  NaN
```

Convert the column numbers into the second-level index, then the second-level index into a column of its own:

```
df_col = df_ser.stack().reset_index(level=1)

#   level_1  0
#0        0  a
#0        1  b
#0        2  f
#....
```

Count the combinations. This is your answer:

```
output = df_col.groupby(['level_1', 0]).size()

#level_1  0
#0        a    4
#1        b    2
#         c    1
#         d    1
#2        c    1
#         d    1
#         f    1
#3        e    2
```

You can have it as dictionary:

```
output.to_dict()
#{(0, 'a'): 4, (1, 'b'): 2, (1, 'c'): 1, (1, 'd'): 1, 
# (2, 'c'): 1, (2, 'd'): 1, (2, 'f'): 1, (3, 'e'): 2}
```

**All in one line:**

```
dataframe.sequence_list.apply(pd.Series)\      
         .stack().reset_index(level=1)\
         .groupby(['level_1',0]).size().to_dict()
```

Comment: `apply(pd.Series` is very slow, use `pd.DataFrame()` instead ;)

Comment: @RafaelC I do not think pd.DataFrame can be used here.

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame(df.col.tolist())`

Comment: @RafaelC What is `col`?

Comment: Your column name ;} change for `sequence_list`, I guess thats what youre using

Comment: I see. It 's sequence_list, because that's how the OP named it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. I think I have got this problem resolved. And I will try both within all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

#### `Setup`

Using the setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [['a','b', 'f', 'e'], ['a','c', 'd', 'e'], ['a','d'], ['a','b', 'c']]})

col
0   [a, b, f, e]
1   [a, c, d, e]
2   [a, d]
3   [a, b, c]
```

You can `apply`+`Counter`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.col.tolist()).apply(Counter)
```

which yields

```
0                             {'a': 4}
1             {'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
2    {'f': 1, 'd': 1, None: 1, 'c': 1}
3                    {'e': 2, None: 2}
dtype: object
```

for each index.

You can just parse your data the way you need, e.g. fill your dicts now to add the zeroes or disconsider, if thats the case, the `None`s.